# Is there any elegant way? (type parameter pack)

Tags: c++, templates, recursion, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to make a function that accepts types and call itself again by looping or recursion.

What I had already tried was below, but it only called the base function (Called base function with `AModule` class and didn't call the function with `BModule.`

```cpp
class AModule {
};
class BModule {
};

auto main() -> int {
  init<AModule, BModule>()
  return 0;
}

template<typename Module>
void init() {
  // BASE FUNCTION
  // Do something
}

template<typename... Modules>
void init() {
  (init<Modules>(), ...)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what the problem is? The code you're providing shouldn't compile at all (`init` isn't declared before `main`) - and even if you fix that an add the missing semicolons, I wouldn't expect the behavior you're describing (calls `init<A>` but not `init<B>`), I would expect an ambiguous call to `init<B>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the code in your example you're using template-folding, a new C++17 feature that permit you to avoid recursion.

But, to avoid a name collision, I suggest to call the base version in a different way; say `do_something()`

```
template<typename Module>
void do_something() {
  // BASE FUNCTION
  // Do something
}

template<typename... Modules>
void init() {
  (do_something<Modules>(), ...);
}
```

If you really want use recursive way, you can do something as follows

```
template <int = 0>
void init ()
 {
  // stop recursion; do nothing
 }

template <typename Head, typename ... Tail>
void init () 
 {
   // do something with Head

   // recursively call init()
   init<Tail...>();
 }
```

The trick is that calling `init<Tail...>();`, until `Tail...` isn't empty is called the `Head`/`Tail...` recursive version.

When `Tail...` is empty, `init<Tail...>()` is `init<>()` so the `Head`/`Tail...` version doesn't matches anymore (there isn't a `Head`) but matches the `int = 0` version; so `init<>()` become `init<0>()` and the ground-do-nothing case stops recursion.

Answer (score 1):

In your code (once syntax errors were fixed), both `init()` calls were valid for 1 template parameter, so the call was ambiguous.   By making the multi-init call require at least 2 parameters, that ambiguity is removed.

```
// bogus type that just prints an error message including the type it is parameterized with
template<typename T>
struct printer;

template<typename Module>
void init() {
 printer<Module>{}; // this is an error just to show you that it's getting called with both types
}

// only call this if it's called with 2 or more types, otherwise just use the other init()
template<typename T1, typename T2, typename... Modules>
void init() {
    init<T1>();
    init<T2>();
  (init<Modules>(), ...);
}

class AModule {
};
class BModule {
};

auto main() -> int {
  init<AModule, BModule>();
  return 0;
}
```

live: https://godbolt.org/z/D-eh2G